# Django rest framework add field to serializer that does not get added to every entry

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to add data to a serializer, but I am having trouble getting it to only add the field to the response once instead of for each entry.

Here is my code:

```
class FriendGiftSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    giftDisplayData = AllGiftSerializer(source='giftId', required=True)
    bestMatch = serializers.IntegerField()
    topAttribute = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = FriendGift
        fields = ('giftId', 'giftDisplayData', 'bestMatch', 'topAttribute')

    def get_topAttribute(self, obj):
        return self.context["top_attribute"]
```

And the topAttribute field is added to every instance of FriendGift instead of just once at the end. I feel like I am missing something small, but am having trouble finding the right resource for how to solve this. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

you need create context and pass it into Serializer like this:

```
context_obj = {'top_attribute': 'example'}

serializer = FriendGiftSerializer(instance=query_set, many=True, context=context_obj)
return serializer.data
```

and you can get `self.context["top_attribute"]` inside.

Comment: So I am getting the context successfully into the serializer, but when I add it gets added to each instance of FriendGift when I only need the value to appear once for the whole set.

Comment: you mean you want value of `top_attribute` appear only one time in final resuts, instead of appear with each item in queryset ? In this case, i think we can modify serializer.data.

Comment: Yeah that's the goal. Hmm thanks I will look up modifying the serializer.data

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_topAttribute(self, obj):
    return self.context.pop("top_attribute", None)
```

Or

```
def get_topAttribute(self, obj):
    if not self.context.get('is_showed'):
        self.context['is_showed'] = True
        return self.context["top_attribute"]
    return None
```

I think it's a little tricky.

Comment: This solution is better than what I had because it is setting the value for the first item, but it still keeps a null value for that field for all of the remaining items.

I was hoping there would be a way to return it separate from the rest of the items. Like how some apis would return count or something similar as a separate field from the rest of the items.